# Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-limit

This error message is being presented, any suggestions?

> Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   43148176 bytes) in php

Comment: Increase your maximum memory limit to 64MB in your php.ini file. [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1G1GGLQ_ENUS302&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&q=increase+memory+limit+php&spell=1) But could I ask why you are trying to allocate that much memory? What line of code does it fail at?

Comment: What is the script doing when it fails? can you post the code?

Comment: PHP can be very inefficient with memory usage, I have often seen simple datagrids blow well into 80mb with a mere couple hundred records.  This seems to especially happen when you go the OOP route.

Comment: It's not necessarily a language problem - it's an algorithm problem, too. Too many PHP programmers do repeated actions on a whole dataset rather than doing all processing on one item at a time.

Comment: we are trying to read a .txt file

Comment: PHP is efficient if you use it right. It is hard though to keep track of all of your objects due to the managed nature of the runtime - not unlike C#. But too many high-level programmers period (including C#) do not have an appreciation of how their code affects the resources it runs on.

Comment: Looks like a very huge txt file.

Comment: Conventionally, you read files that are of potentially large or arbitrary size one line at a time, over-writing the previous line memory with each line read. Or you may just want to tail or head the file to get the latest entries. Upping your memory allocation as the file grows is not the answer.

Answer (score 400, accepted):

If your script is **expected** to allocate that big amount of memory, then you can increase the memory limit by adding this line to your php file

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '44M');
```

where `44M` is the amount you expect to be consumed.

**However**, most of time this error message means that **the script is doing something wrong** and increasing the memory limit will just result in the same error message with different numbers.

Therefore, instead of increasing the memory limit you must rewrite the code so it won't allocate that much memory. For example, processing large amounts of data in smaller chunks, unsetting variables that hold large values but not needed anymore, etc.

Comment: You still should check *why* the memory is exhausted. Maybe you don't need to read the whole file, maybe read it sequentially.

Comment: Worked great. I know _why_ memory was being exhausted - I'm using Zend-Feed to consume a rather large-ish Atom feed. I can't control the size of it or do anything other than swallow the whole feed in one pull, so bumping the memory limit for that one operation solved it. Cheers!

Comment: - @panidarapu and @Don Jones: Depending on the amount of memory, and *how* this script is used, it could be dangerous to allow the change in memory usage in this way. Don, in your case, you can likely break the feed down into smaller chunks and parse what you need. Glad it works, but be careful.

Comment: This suggestion worked for me. Dynamically increasing memory limit in the script is done via function ini_set():

ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');

i used same thing but it showing same problem

Comment: @panidarapu: You might not have permissions to increase the memory limit - especially if you're on a shared host.

Comment: If this doesn't work, add 'php_value memory_limit 50M' in your .htaccess. Replace 50M with your own value.

Comment: This is a bad idea that potentially leaves your server open to malicious attacks via large data posts.

Comment: If anyone else is running into this problem with Wordpress, try setting PHP's memory limits within wp-config.php. Here's the code: `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');`

Comment: @panidarapu To use unlimited memory is too much, isn't it?

Comment: I had this error in /wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/wp-langs.php. Changing memory wasn't possible/didn;t work. I just deleted most part of the file (from $lang= on )This worked (so now the editor is in english, but so what).

Comment: Guys, please don't go for this quick fix. It can hurt you in long run. As a good programmer, you should figure-out the reason behind this memory consumption & increase as required instead of keeping it `UNLIMITED`.

Comment: Wow, this massively upvoted answer seems like really bad practice to me. -1!

Comment: I also feel it's dangerous but what's the worst that can happen in the future? Bring down the server? What if it's down currently? Can it make it get any worse? What if you're using a third party app and cannot change the code?

Comment: I had just also this error in my script. It was because I came in an endless loop, which resulted in the Stack Overflow

Comment: Better try to use something like `memory_get_usage` to diagnose the cause. In my case it was an infinite loop. And it is not good to have infinite loops in production :)

Comment: This is an AWFUL solution. Only use this to get things working enough so that you can identify the high memory usage and REDUCE it. This will KILL your production server when you get another memory bug. Rather than killing the one bad request, it will knock out quite a bit more.

Comment: Setting unlimited memory is a very bad idea. It hides the memory consumption of the program, which can certainly be lowered. Moreover, if this is running on a server and called several times a second it will hog the server memory or, probably, end dying on some instances. You MUST analyze your program with memory_get_usage() traces at various places, although values given by this function are sometimes disturbing due to the block-allocation scheme of PHP.

Comment: It doesn't work on PHP 5.6 on Windows. I get a similar exhausted memory error.

Comment: This is a great article on this error and why NOT to use UNLIMITED memory on a server. Use -1 on a dev for testing only but not on production.
https://www.airpair.com/php/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size

Comment: Following guidance here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255198/how-to-handle-historical-highly-upvoted-but-completely-incorrect-answers

I've had to downvote your answer, as it doesn't fix the problem you described, only masks it - and potentially causes further issues later down the line.

Comment: This is very bad. If you do this, you might consume a considerable amount of server memory and consequences might be critical

Comment: I agree this is a bad solution because of the potential future risk it creates, but I chose it because it was a quick fix. I was trying to update a Joomla! install to the latest version. Once I was able to do that, I removed the ini_set addition immediately.

Comment: this is not a recommended method. it's like you are telling to take as much as memory needed. so run this command "php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento" in Magento root directory

Comment: When you don't like your webserver, set memory limit to infinite... LOL

Comment: awesome init_set but I have a question is this safe to use for a server?

Comment: I would **never, ever** recommend setting the memory limit to -1 (unlimited) in a production environment. That's a recipe for disaster. Don't make that newbie mistake.
-------------------------
So how do you do this? Simple —If you do it this way, you can give PHP extra memory only when that piece of code gets called rather than increasing the memory limit for all PHP processes.

If by increasing the memory limit you have gotten rid of the error and your code now works, you'll need to take measures to decrease that memory usage.

Comment: In your .htaccess you can add:

PHP 5.x

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value memory_limit 64M
</IfModule>
PHP 7.x

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
    php_value memory_limit 64M
</IfModule>

Comment: `ini_set('memory_limit', '44M');` worked well in my wordpress case.

Comment: This does not really solve the issue, it just is a workaround for a still existing problem.

Answer (score 71):

Here are two simple methods to increase the limit on shared hosting:

1. If you have access to your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini
   If your line shows 32M try 64M:
   `memory_limit = 64M ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (64MB)`
2. If you don't have access to PHP.ini try adding this to an .htaccess file:
   `php_value memory_limit 64M`

Answer (score 54):

Your script is using too much memory. This can often happen in PHP if you have a loop that has run out of control and you are creating objects or adding to arrays on each pass of the loop.

Check for infinite loops.

If that isn't the problem, try and help out PHP by destroying objects that you are finished with by setting them to null. eg. `$OldVar = null;`

Check the code where the error actually happens as well. Would you expect that line to be allocating a massive amount of memory? If not, try and figure out what has gone wrong...

Comment: I had this exact problem - turned out I had inadvertedly created a recursive function - and thus it ran out of memory at any random time during code execution.

This had the upside of me now having the world's most memory efficient code, created in the hunt for a memory leak.

Comment: For the sake of others who will chase a rabbit down a hole. Doctrine in Symfony i think has an issue with monolog and when there is PDO exception it will create an infinite loop of exceptions as it will try an exception for the exception thus hiding the real issue (a corrupted db file in my case).

Answer (score 49):

Doing :

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

is never good. If you want to read a very large file, it is a best practise to copy it bit by bit. Try the following code for best practise.

```
$path = 'path_to_file_.txt';

$file = fopen($path, 'r');
$len = 1024; // 1MB is reasonable for me. You can choose anything though, but do not make it too big
$output = fread( $file, $len );

while (!feof($file)) {
    $output .= fread( $file, $len );
}

fclose($file);

echo 'Output is: ' . $output;
```

Comment: Can't believe all these people recommending to set memory_limit to -1... Crazy thing to do on a production server. Thanks for a much cleaner solution.

Comment: While at "best practice", it is good to close the file handler after the `while` loop: `fclose($file)`

Comment: @assetCorp How does this help, provided the file has for example 100MiB and PHP memory limit is still set to 32 MiB. You read it by secure chunks of 1MiB, but then append it into a variable that is going to use all the available memory once the loop reaches 31. iteration. How is it any better? Only outputting the chunks similarly not to require storing them all in one variable would help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 26):

I have faced same problem in php7.2 with laravel 5.6. I just increase the amount of variable `memory_limit = 128M` in php.ini as my applications demand. It might be 256M/512M/1048M.....Now it works fine.

Comment: This can work as a short-term solution, but unless you're expecting this kind of memory usage, it's likely a sign that something is wrong.

Answer (score 22):

It is unfortunately easy to program in PHP in a way that consumes memory faster than you realise. Copying strings, arrays and objects instead of using references will do it, though PHP 5 is supposed to do this more automatically than in PHP 4. But dealing with your data set in entirety over several steps is also wasteful compared to processing the smallest logical unit at a time. The classic example is working with large resultsets from a database: most programmers fetch the entire resultset into an array and then loop over it one or more times with `foreach()`. It is much more memory efficient to use a `while()` loop to fetch and process one row at a time. The same thing applies to processing a file.

Comment: It seems pretty likely that this is what does it.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to read large files, you should read them bit by bit instead of reading them at once.
It’s simple math: If you read a 1 MB large file at once, than at least 1 MB of memory is needed at the same time to hold the data.

So you should read them bit by bit using `fopen` & `fread`.

Comment: Solved this by using: `$fh = fopen($folder.'/'.$filename, "rb") or die(); $buffer = 1024*1024; while (!feof($fh)) { print(fread($fh, $buffer)); flush(); } fclose($fh);`

Answer (score 9):

You can increase the memory allowed to php script by executing the following line above all the codes in the script:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','-1'); // enabled the full memory available.
```

And also de allocate the unwanted variables in the script.

Comment: This isn't a great solution.  This means (I believe) that you're letting the script run wild and use as much memory as it wants.  Errors about using too much memory are likely a sign that something is wrong, so this gets rid of the symptom but kind of lets the problem get bigger (literally).

Answer (score 8):

I was also having the same problem, looked for phpinfo.ini, php.ini or .htaccess files to no avail. Finally I have looked at some php files, opened them and checked the codes inside for memory. Finally this solution was what I come out with and it worked for me. I was using wordpress, so this solution might only work for wordpress memory size limit problem.
My solution, open **default-constants.php** file in **/public_html/wp-includes** folder. Open that file with code editor, and find memory settings under `wp_initial_constants` scope, or just Ctrl+F it to find the word "memory". There you will come over `WP_MEMORY_LIMIT` and `WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT`. Just increase it, it was 64 MB in my case, I increased it to 128 MB and then to 200 MB.

```
// Define memory limits.
if ( ! defined( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT' ) ) {
    if ( false === wp_is_ini_value_changeable( 'memory_limit' ) ) {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', $current_limit );
    } elseif ( is_multisite() ) {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '200M' );
    } else {
        define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M' );
    }
}

if ( ! defined( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT' ) ) {
    if ( false === wp_is_ini_value_changeable( 'memory_limit' ) ) {
        define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', $current_limit );
    } elseif ( -1 === $current_limit_int || $current_limit_int > 268435456 /* = 256M */ ) {
        define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', $current_limit );
    } else {
        define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
    }
}
```

Btw, please don't do the following code, because that's bad practice:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Comment: Works for wordpress websites, where access is not available for .htaccess and php.ini files. +1

Comment: I'd say that changing those limits on a 'core' WordPress file is not really a good idea; you can so very easily add those limits on `wp-config.php` instead, where they will not get overwritten by future WordPress updates.
Also, a few security plugins (such as WordFence, for instance) will complain if 'core' WordPress files are changed...

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn I don't know how to do that, can you elaborate it, please?

Comment: Oh... just edit `wp-config.php` and add the two lines there (i .e. `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '200M' );` and `define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );`. Unlike the files on the 'core' WP (namely, everything under `wp-includes`), which will be overwritten by WP upgrades, `wp-config.php` will not — it's there exactly for the exact purpose of overriding WP constants!

Comment: "bad practice" is situational. `-1` is fine for short-running processes. For example a php builder container that's used for running unit tests or composer installs/etc. Just don't run your production site with it set like that.

Comment: If in hurry do ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); and if it is a one time operation, like a seeder, return it then to the previous value

Answer (score 7):

I notice many answers just try to increase the amount of memory given to a script which has its place but more often than not it means that something is being too liberal with memory due to an unforseen amount of volume or size. Obviously if your not the author of a script your at the mercy of the author unless your feeling ambitious :) The PHP docs even say memory issues are due to "[poorly written scripts](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)"

It should be mentioned that `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` (no limit) can cause server instability as `0 bytes free = bad things`. Instead, find a reasonable balance by what your script is trying to do and the amount of available memory on a machine.

**A better approach:** If you are the author of the script (or ambitious) you can debug such memory issues with [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/index.php). The latest version (2.6.0 - released 2018-01-29) brought back memory profiling that shows you what function calls are consuming large amounts of memory. It exposes issues in the script that are otherwise hard to find. Usually, the inefficiencies are in a loop that isn't expecting the volume it's receiving, but each case will be left as an exercise to the reader :)

The [xdebug documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) is helpful, but it boils down to 3 steps:

1. [Install It](https://xdebug.org/download.php) - Available through `apt-get` and `yum` etc
2. [Configure it](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) - xdebug.ini: `xdebug.profiler_enable = 1`, `xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /where/ever/`
3. View the profiles in a tool like [QCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qcachegrindwin/), [KCacheGrind](https://kcachegrind.github.io/)

Answer (score 5):

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Comment: @Pang ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to read a file, that will take up memory in PHP. For instance, if you are trying to open up and read an MP3 file ( like, say, $data = file("http://mydomain.com/path/sample.mp3" ) it is going to pull it all into memory.

As Nelson suggests, you can work to increase your maximum memory limit if you actually need to be using this much memory.

Answer (score 2):

I want to share my experience on this issue!

Suppose you have a class A and class B.

```
class A {
    protected $userB;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->userB = new B();
    }
}

class B {
    protected $userA;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->userA = new A();
    }
}
```

this will initiate a chain formation of objects which may be create this kind of issue!

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar situation and we tried out given at the top of the answers
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
and everything worked fine, compressed images files greater than 1MB to KBs.

Answer (score 1):

Write

`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

in your index.php at the top after opening of php tag

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error message after switching to a new theme in Wordpress. PHP was running version 5.3 so I switched to 7.2. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a shared hosting, you will not be able to enforce the increment in the php size limit.

Just go to your cpanel and upgrade your php version to 7.1 and above then you are good to go.

Comment: i''m on 7.4, still facing.

Comment: The issue was resolved when I upgrade php to 7.1. Can you try php 7.1 or 7.2

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following command `composer update`, and now are working. If its not solve your problem increase your memory limit in `memory_limit` in the `php.ini` file.

Answer (score -1):

wordpress users add line:

`@ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

in wp-settings.php which you can find in the wordpress installed root folder

Answer (score -1):

I hadn't renewed my hosting and the database was read-only. Joomla needed to write the session and couldn't do it.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue which running php in command line. Recently, I had changes the php.ini file and did a mistake while changing the php.ini

This is for php7.0

> path to php.ini where I made mistake: `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`

I had set `memory_limit = 256` (which means `256 bytes`) 
 instead of `memory_limit = 256M` (which means `256 Mega bytes`).

> ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB) 
>   ; http://php.net/memory-limit 
>  `memory_limit = 128M`

Once I corrected it, my process started running fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Laravel, then use these ways:

```
public function getClientsListApi(Request $request){
      print_r($request->all()); //for all request
      print_r($request->name); //for all name 
}
```

instead of

```
public function getClientsListApi(Request $request){
      print_r($request); // it show error as above mention
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require mageplaza/module-core
```

Answer (score -1):

wordpress users add line:

```
@ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

or

set memory_limit to -1 in cpanel

[image]