# can't upload a bigdata in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, bigdata, fatal-error, filesize

I can't upload a bigdata in PhpMyAdmin.I have changed upload_max_filesize, post_max_size and restared my Apache. So now I see that the upload_max_filesize is 128 M, but there is still bug (( "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 224119 bytes) in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.0.4\libraries\plugins\import\ImportCsv.class.php on line 4 " Please help me if you can!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your memory_limit in php.ini is too low, set currently to 128M. If you increase it to 256M and restart apache, that should be big enough to allow it.

See also this question which is similar: [Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter)

Comment: I've changed memory_limit, but I still have a bug. As I see, an error is in "ImportCsv.class.php". But I can't detect it. Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: So a solution that I found =) I created my db by myself and after that I uploaded a big data .csv via CSV using LOAD DATA. So for the moment it works youpiii =)

Comment: cool. If you write what worked for you as an answer, you can check it off so people searching for this question will more easily see the solution!