# PhpMyAdmin | Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate xxxxxx bytes) in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, fatal-error

I'm tying to find the cause of this error but I'm failing. I've have installed PhpMyAdmin on my server and right now on the footer of every page I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10934248 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

As you can see I've tried di upgrade the memory_limit (from 2MB to 128MB) but I still getting this error. Right now it appears every time I login in PhpMyAdmin console, also if I don't do any opertation. Do you have any suggestion?

I've tried to follow some answer that I find on the web, but no one seems to resolve the problem. Also I can't find the file that throw the error becasue it's "Unknow" and I can't understand who is asking for such quantity of memory.

Comment: Does your new memory limit really work? How did you upgrade the memory limit? Checked phpinfo() after the change?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted the apache server and PHP see my new limit `(134217728 bytes exhausted)`.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: @MarcDelisle 5.5.33-cll-lve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use 128MB use 128M, seriously, try it.

Comment: Hey ..its a great help. I was using 512MB but changed to 512 . It works .. even before i tried setting -1 and 0 to memory_limit  but that doesnt help. Can you please tell me why this solve this? @corzoit

Comment: Yes this worked, I'd be interested to know why this fixes it.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but I started having the same issue today on Apache running on a Linode virtual server.  In my case, the solution was simply to **enable Zend Opcache**.  It was disabled due to an error in one of the ini files in '/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/' directory.

I was getting intermittent errors, where most of the time pages and images would load just fine, but once in a while they would fail.  Images would be broken and instead of seeing a page I would get "connection error".

These are some additional errors I was seeing in the Apache's error.log file:

```
[core:notice] [pid 8186] AH00052: child pid 9008 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[core:notice] [pid 8186] AH00052: child pid 9007 exit signal Aborted (6)
*** Error in `/usr/sbin/apache2': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f56840b63c0 ***
```

and of course the infamous:

```
[:error] [pid 8829] [client nnn.nnn.nnn.n:24471] PHP Fatal error:
  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to 
  allocate 94008222532912 bytes) in Unknown on line 0, referer:
  https://www.mysiteurlhere.com/node/page
```

After enabling zend opcache, there are no more errors in error.log, and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your php script,

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');  // -1 here implies no limit, you can even set it to a bigger number like '192M' for 192Mb space.
```

This will override the default memory limit.

This question has already been answered many times.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to know which is the casue of this problem. Infact, I've not started any command.

Comment: So without running any big script you are getting this Fatal error?

Comment: Right, I've getting this script after I logged-in in PhpMyAdmin. But despite the error I can operate without any problem - More precisely once I've tried to import a very large sql file, but as expected it failed.

Comment: After you tried to import a big sql file, this error started showing up, is it? Did you try importing by phpmyadmin import or did you write a php script ? If through php, pls show us your code.

Comment: _After you tried to import a big sql file, this error started showing up?_, sincerly I don't know, becasue the error is always show in the bottom on the page. Anyway, I've tried to import the sql file directly from the 'Import' page of PhpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1):

If changes for php.ini doesn't take affect for you, try to change phpmyadmin's **config.inc.php**. In most cases it locates at /etc/phpmyadmin. Insert rows bellow before `?>` tag:

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 300000;
$cfg['MemoryLimit'] = -1;
```

You may set `$cfg['MemoryLimit']` to 0. In that case the value will be taken from php.ini

Answer (score 0):

When the number of tables in the database became more than 9400, I faced the same problem.

The problem appeared only when I entered a query to the database using phpmyadmin. Some time later, after the beginning of the input query on the screen there was a 500 error and logs the error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10934248 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

The solution was to comment out part of the code in the db_sql_autocomplete.php , which is located in the phpmyadmin folder.

The code **db_sql_autocomplete.php**:

```html
<?php
 
use PhpMyAdmin\Response;
require_once 'libraries/common.inc.php';

/*
if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['EnableAutocompleteForTablesAndColumns']) {
    $db = isset($_POST['db']) ? $_POST['db'] : $GLOBALS['db'];
    $sql_autocomplete = array();
    if ($db) {
        $tableNames = $GLOBALS['dbi']->getTables($db);
        foreach ($tableNames as $tableName) {
            $sql_autocomplete[$tableName] = $GLOBALS['dbi']->getColumns(
                $db, $tableName
            );
        }
    }
} else {*/
    $sql_autocomplete = true;
//}
$response = Response::getInstance();
$response->addJSON("tables", json_encode($sql_autocomplete));
```