# Open Cart Fatal error: Allowed memory size Issue

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, opencart

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 38312699 bytes) in
>   /home1/eshoppaz/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php
>   on line 58

How do I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: You have access to php.ini file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the memory_limit on the root and within the admin folder, I noticed that nobody pointed this out and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the php.ini file, set the `memory_limit` option to `128M`.

If you don't have access to it, you can try to set it in the .htaccess with:

```
php_value memory_limit 128M
```

If you change it on php.ini file don't forget restart the server after change the value.

Your server have the memory_limit set to 64Mb and Open Cart need a little more (with your error it needs 36Mb more). Also i seen on other forums that people set memory_limit to 256M to avoid problems.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your response. This is what I have in my php.ini file:
max_execution_time = 30     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 128M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (16MB)

Comment: Try to change the memory_limit to 256M, restart the server and try again. I'm sure that the problem is the memory_limit property but i'm not sure 100% how to fix it haha. For me, it works when I change it on the php.ini file so, maybe works.

Comment: Ok, let me know if not and we can find what's the problem ;). Regards