# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 259072 bytes)

Tags: google-app-engine, joomla, fatal-error, memory-size

what is this error mean and how do i over come this?
 am getting this error when i run my joomla using Google App Engine. thanks in advance.

Comment: Your allowed memory size in php.ini is 128mb and your script needs more memory. These posts may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte

Answer (score 4):

Your PHP configuration at the server has a memory limit , which is rather low.
I'd recommend to set it to 32 Mb.

I solve it, by writing down a line in "configuration.php" and "configuration.php-dist":

```
ini_mem('memory_limit','12M');
```

For unlimited memory usage of server

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```