# CakePHP Allowed Memory Size Error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm using CakePHP 2.3
I'm getting this error when accessing a CakePHP website:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4386075 bytes) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\lib\Cake\Event\CakeEventManager.php on line 246

It doesn't seem to be a loop, looks like something related with sessions as it fails just after trying to read a session variable with `$this->Session->read('Auth.User.isAdmin')`.

Before that, I can print and `die()` without problems.

---

**Update:**

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12273327 bytes) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tlm\lib\Cake\Event\CakeEventManager.php on line 246

**Update 2**

After setting the limit to 1500M

> PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 1307312128) (tried to allocate 23778447 bytes) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tlm\lib\Cake\View\View.php on line 926
>   PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tlm\lib\Cake\Error\ErrorHandler.php on line 116

**Update 3**

I'm using PHP 5.5.6. After updating to CakePHP 2.6 by replacing the `lib` folder, I'm getting the same error multiple times and after like 30 lines of that same error, I get the memory one.

> PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tlm\app\Plugin\Combinator\View\Helper\CombinatorHelper.php on line 33
>
> PHP Strict Standards: Only ...
>
> PHP Strict Standards: Only ...
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3704512 bytes) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tlm\lib\Cake\View\View.php on line 958
>
> PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tlm\app\Plugin\Combinator\View\Helper\CombinatorHelper.php on line 33
>
> PHP Strict Standards: Only ...
>
> PHP Strict Standards: Only ...

Comment: This is not a cakephp specific problem, you probably have an infinite loop or something similar that is consuming all your memory.

Comment: Update to the current master branch version where the stacktrace for fatal errors are printed now as well ( https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/5053 ). And debug it this way to have more information on what happened.

Comment: @mark changing from version 2.3 to the current one 2.6 I'm afraid some things can stop working due to internal changes in cakePHP.

Comment: @Alvaro , at least u can try 2.6 on Development instance

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird updated to 2.6. I've updated my question with the latest errors.

Comment: Combinator plugin Doesnt work :) try letest version of it too.

Comment: You can also cherry pick the changes in that PR :) No need to fully upgrade just for getting a strack trace my friend.

Comment: Looking at your third update, it doesn't seem that you have installed/enabled xdebug (which is required for the change mentioned by @mark)!?

Comment: I thing that is a error in a bucle or pagination or maybe when do you want show the data, do you have a db of test? because you need a db with just a few files and this can give you a error more specific.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases it helps to temporary put this method in AppController:

```
public function appError($method, $messages) {
    die('Application error: called handler method ' . $method);
}
```

This usually gives me a hint where to look further.

Answer (score 0):

Edit php.ini and set `memory_limit` to great extent than currently set.

Like set `memory_limit = 512M`

**Update**

increase max_execution_time

Comment: This problem was not occurring before. Why should it now?

Comment: Hi you never know when memory was consumed less , and when will be consumed more ok?

Comment: Updated question. Still getting and error with 512.

Comment: wat was old set value ?

Comment: Updated question again using 1512M. (the old value was 128M)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter

Comment: `max_execution_time` is set to 30, which I believe is the normal one to use.

Comment: I got same error in MAGENTO , when data was getting Recursively handled.

Comment: Updated answer with 2.6 installed.

Answer (score 0):

After experiencing a similar error, it looks like the problem exists in CakeSession.php line 489:

```
throw new CakeSessionException(sprintf(
    __d('cake_dev', 'Unable to configure the session, setting %s failed.'),
    $setting
));
```

This seems to be causing the infinite loop, and exiting here will stop it. I don't know exactly why this is causing a loop, but the the reason it does is because CakePHP can't set some of your php.ini variables using `ini_set`. If you print out `$setting` and `$value` at this point you'll be able to see what the problem variables are. For me is was `session.auto_start`, which was set in the `_defaultConfig` function in this file. I commented out the lines which set this which resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and this helped:
I simply changed the `$this->set('votingBookings')` into `$this->set('bookings')` in the controller file. hope that helps anybody. Love SO and want to contribute my 2 cents. cheers `:D`