# Symfony2 - PHP fatal error (out of memory) cause by too many query

Tags: php, symfony

I am working with Symfony (const version="2.5") and using XAMPP with PHP version of 5.5. My problem is I get a fatal error: 'Allowed memory size....'.When I check my php error logs.
I have these errors showing up:

> > [06-May-2015 03:08:45 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 48 bytes)
> >     in
> >     C:\xampp\htdocs\Editracker\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataCollector\DoctrineDataCollector.php
> >     on line 119
>
> [06-May-2015 03:08:49 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory
>   size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40 bytes) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Editracker\app\bootstrap.php.cache on line 2003
>
> [06-May-2015 03:54:14 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory
>   size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36 bytes) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Editracker\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataCollector\DoctrineDataCollector.php
>   on line 120

How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml)

Comment: You should first explain what exactly you are working on, share that code and then put the error you are facing. Providing details will help get the right feedback.

Comment: @Baig what details you need to help me? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the memory limit in your `php.ini` file by setting:

`memory_limit='256M'`

Comment: OP should __not__ do this, he should find out where the mem leak is occuring...

Comment: thats not really solving the origin of the problem, but solving the consequence of the problem