# Magento layered navigation CMS page : allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php, magento, layered-navigation

I created a CMS page in magento 1.9 which has a product collection
So I decided to put a layered navigation in the left column (the design is 2 column with a left one)

XML code for left reference :

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

It worked great but since 2 days I got an error :

I have an Allowed memory size exhausted for the method `$this->getFilters()`

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

It is a common error with Open Source Softwares. "Allowed memory size error." Increasing the memory limit is an easy solution. This memory_limit can be changed in the php.ini in the public_html folder in your hosting account.

- Find the following section in the php.ini file.

  `max_execution_time = 30`
  `max_input_time = 60`
  `memory_limit = 128M`

Try increase the memory_limit value to 256M.
If the php memory_limit is already at 256M, you can increase it to 512M.

Save the changes. If you don't have access to php.ini file then you can define memory_limit in your .htaccess file.

More explanation: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php-troubleshooting/allowed-memory-size-exausted

Need more information? Read here: [Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml)

If it doesn't work then it is because of the code you've written for the product collection. Try to optimize your code. This article may help you to work with large collection. http://inchoo.net/magento/working-with-large-magento-collections/

Answer (score 0):

try to post your question here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/

could get more views and better help.

In last couple of days you changed some settings in configuration->catalog did you? I guess somewhere around layered navigation right ? try to revert that back and see if that helps

Comment: I didn't change anything in configuration->catalog .. But I added some new categories, I was really near the memory limit and the few categories I added were too much ? ..