# Warning: is_readable() [...]: open_basedir restriction in effect. AND Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php, wordpress, localization, themes, wordpress-theming

A while back, I tried uploading to WordPress a theme via FTP, but whenever I try to see the preview, it keeps giving me the following error:

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 261904 bytes) in E:\Domains\joseramosadvogados.com.br\wwwroot\wp-includes\option.php on line 818

```
/**
* Delete user interface settings.
*
* Deleting settings would reset them to the defaults.
* This function has to be used before any output has started as it calls setcookie().
*
* @since 2.7.0
*
* @param mixed $names The name or array of names of the setting to be deleted.
* @return bool true if deleted successfully/false if not.
*/

function delete_user_setting( $names ) {

if ( headers_sent() ) {
    return false;
}

$all_user_settings = get_all_user_settings();
$names = (array) $names;
$deleted = false;

foreach ( $names as $name ) {
    if ( isset( $all_user_settings[$name] ) ) {
        unset( $all_user_settings[$name] );
        $deleted = true;                      /*line 818*/
    }
}

if ( $deleted ) {
    return wp_set_all_user_settings( $all_user_settings );
}

return false;
}
```

But a while then it gave me another error screen:

> PHP Warning:  is_readable() [function.is-readable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/languages//pt_BR.mo) is not within the allowed path(s): (E:\Domains\joseramosadvogados.com.br) in E:\Domains\joseramosadvogados.com.br\wwwroot\wp-includes\l10n.php on line 471

```
/**
 * Filter MO file path for loading translations for a specific text domain.
 *
 * @since 2.9.0
 *
 * @param string $mofile Path to the MO file.
 * @param string $domain Text domain. Unique identifier for retrieving translated strings.
 */
$mofile = apply_filters( 'load_textdomain_mofile', $mofile, $domain );

if ( !is_readable( $mofile ) ) return false;           /*line 471*/

$mo = new MO();
if ( !$mo->import_from_file( $mofile ) ) return false;

if ( isset( $l10n[$domain] ) )
    $mo->merge_with( $l10n[$domain] );

$l10n[$domain] = &$mo;

return true;
}
```

I have little knowledge on PHP, so could you guys help me find the root of these two problems? (I've tried some stuff people said through the internet, like .htaccess, add "set_include_path('.');" after the `<?php` line, deactivating the plugins...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml)

Answer (score 0):

`open_basedir restriction in effect` means you're using a webhost that is living in the dark ages. No one has `open_basedir` disabled these days.

And the fact that PHP doesn't have enough memory to run also points to the host. Try adding the "define" line below in your [wp-config.php](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) file a few lines of white space below the opening  `<?php` in the file:

`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`

and see if you can at least get rid of the memory error.

If not, find a new webhost.