# PHP memory size issue

Tags: php, algorithm

Hello I need to analyze around 50,063,860 combinations for my fantasy roster. It's 60 pick 6.

I am trying to generate all possible combinations passing the names array to the Math_Combinatorics pearl library:

$n is an array of 60 elements,

`$result = $combinatorics->combinations( $n, 6);`

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /usr/share/php/Math/Combinatorics.php on line 126**

Is there anyway to allocate more memory or feed it less entries at one time so it does not crash?

Comment: May I ask why do you use PHP for such task?

Comment: @tuananh yea probably not a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) in your `php.ini`. From the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit):

> This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate. This helps prevent poorly written scripts for eating up all available memory on a server. Note that to have no memory limit, set this directive to -1.

You can also set this value inline in your script using the [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/ini_set) function or even in an apache virtual host configuration using the [`php_value`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) directive.

Having said that, it would probably behoove you to refactor your code such that not all the permutations need be in memory at once, thereby drastically reducing your program's memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip this error by using `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`. This will override default method.

[PHP allocated Memory Size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

**But** Note this is *not better solution* for it. [Check this out as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18660082/4595675)

And Possible Duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)