# Getting Allowed memory size error on sample data deployment magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

I am trying to install sample data using magento 2 command line utility. But getting blow error when in run "php magento sampledata:deploy" from php command line.

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8388608 bytes) in sionParser.php on line 230

Anyone faced similar error? please suggest me how to resolve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: It's not off topic. Its magento programming related question.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using command,

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

where 6G you can change it.

I have same problems. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the official Magento 2 documentation [does not state in clearly](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2830), but you need at least **768 megabytes of RAM** per a Magento 2 PHP process:

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html#instgde-prereq-timezone
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html#instgde-prereq-timezone
- https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0.0/.htaccess#L40