# How do i process a file in parts

Tags: php, large-files

I have a program that deletes `Hand #[any number]` from a file

```
<?php

$file_name = 'the_file.txt';

$file = file_get_contents($file_name);
$file_handle = fopen($file_name, "w+"); 


fwrite($file_handle, preg_replace("/^(Hand\s#\d+)/m", "", $file));
```

But if I try to input a large file I get:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 68353857 bytes)

I think the solution is to edit 134217728 bytes at a time how would I do this?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml

Comment: @Saty I didn't see any talk of processing the file in parts only changing the memory limit wich I hear is a bad solution for reasons I don't fully understand