# form_validation is not working, it gives an error "exhausted" using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have used `form_validation` on `codeigniter 3.0`. it gives an **error**

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   130968 bytes)

Controller Code:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', "Username", "trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', "Password", "trim|required|min_length[5]");
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->index();
        } else {
            $result = $this->admin_model->check_login();
            if ($result) {
               $user_data = array(
                    'username' => $_POST['username'],
                    'logged_in' => TRUE,
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('login_failed', 'The login info you entered is invalid');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show the query in $this->admin_model->check_login(); ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml

Answer (score 0):

Increase your memory size in php.ini file. It will solve your problem.

```
memory_limit = 12M
```

or use

```
ini_set(“memory_limit”,“12M”);
```

in codeigniter.