# I am getting fatal error memory exhausted in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have upgraded my php version to 5.3 to 5.6 in codeigniter. I am getting error memory exhausted. Before upgrading, site was working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your current memory limit?

You could try increasing your memory limit:

```
editing your php.ini file
memory_limit = 512M
```

OR

```
including this line on the top of your script
ini_set("memory_limit","512M");
```

You could also check if this lines are on your .htaccess:

php_value memory_limit

And check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22283701/6058255

If this doesn't solve your problem, you should find the specific location of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the memory_limit in you PHP.ini

Comment: I did that to ini_set('memory_limit', -1); but still it is not working