# imagecreatetruecolor php uses up too much memory

Tags: php

I have a php code which gets  its value through an ajax call.These values are provided by the crop module that user uses in order to crop the image.

```
<?php

ini_set('Memory_limit', -1);

$imgUrl = $_POST['imgUrl'];
// original sizes
$imgInitW = $_POST['imgInitW'];
$imgInitH = $_POST['imgInitH'];
// resized sizes

$imgW = $_POST['imgW'];
$imgH = $_POST['imgH'];
// offsets
$imgY1 = $_POST['imgY1'];
$imgX1 = $_POST['imgX1'];
// crop box
$cropW = $_POST['cropW'];
$cropH = $_POST['cropH'];
// rotation angle
$angle = $_POST['rotation'];

$jpeg_quality = 100;
$uniquename=uniqid().time();
$output_filename = "croppedimages/".$uniquename;
// uncomment line below to save the cropped image in the same location as the original image.
//$output_filename = dirname($imgUrl). "/croppedImg_".rand();

$what = getimagesize($imgUrl);

switch(strtolower($what['mime']))
{
    case 'image/png':
        $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($imgUrl);
        $type = '.png';
        break;
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgUrl);
        error_log("jpg");
        $type = '.jpeg';
        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($imgUrl);
        $source_image = imagecreatefromgif($imgUrl);
        $type = '.gif';
        break;
    default: die('image type not supported');
}


//Check write Access to Directory

if(!is_writable(dirname($output_filename))){
    $response = Array(
        "status" => 'error',
        "message" => 'Can`t write cropped File'
    );  
}else{

    // resize the original image to size of editor
    $resizedImage = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);
    imagecopyresampled($resizedImage, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imgW, $imgH, $imgInitW, $imgInitH);
    // rotate the rezized image
    $rotated_image = imagerotate($resizedImage, -$angle, 0);
    // find new width & height of rotated image
    $rotated_width = imagesx($rotated_image);
    $rotated_height = imagesy($rotated_image);
    // diff between rotated & original sizes
    $dx = $rotated_width - $imgW;
    $dy = $rotated_height - $imgH;
    // crop rotated image to fit into original rezized rectangle
    $cropped_rotated_image = imagecreatetruecolor($imgW, $imgH);
    imagecolortransparent($cropped_rotated_image, imagecolorallocate($cropped_rotated_image, 0, 0, 0));
    imagecopyresampled($cropped_rotated_image, $rotated_image, 0, 0, $dx / 2, $dy / 2, $imgW, $imgH, $imgW, $imgH);
    // crop image into selected area
    $final_image = imagecreatetruecolor($cropW, $cropH);
    imagecolortransparent($final_image, imagecolorallocate($final_image, 0, 0, 0));
    imagecopyresampled($final_image, $cropped_rotated_image, 0, 0, $imgX1, $imgY1, $cropW, $cropH, $cropW, $cropH);
    // finally output png image
    //imagepng($final_image, $output_filename.$type, $png_quality);
    imagejpeg($final_image, $output_filename.$type, $jpeg_quality);
    $response = Array(
        "status" => 'success',
        "url" => $output_filename.$type,
    );

}
print json_encode($response);
```

Here **cropW** and **cropH** are the values of the cropped image.however this works fine for low resolution images but when an image of high resolution is used console shows an error on `imagecreatetruecolor` function.

> Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted

Now even when i set the memory usage by `ini_set('Memory_limit', -1);`  it still shows me this error.What could be the reason and what would be the solution?

**Note:** I know setting `ini_set('Memory_limit', -1);` is a bad idea.

Comment: Are you self-hosting or on a paid provider?

Comment: working on localhost right  now but might add this module to a live website.I am gonna use some other image processing library.This one here is for learning purposes.

Comment: Are you running suhosin?

Comment: GD has to load the whole image into memory to work with it. You might have better luck using the [ImageMagick functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) which do not have this restriction.

Comment: nope i am not using it @mkaatman

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check your `php.ini` file you will get it's `memory_limit` not `Memory_limit`.

See here:- http://prntscr.com/agxrtt

So change `ini_set('Memory_limit','-1')` to `ini_set('memory_limit',256)` or `ini_set('memory_limit','-1')`