# Fatal error Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted

Tags: php

Fatal error:

> Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32
>   bytes) in
>   /home/studentlms/public_html/application/third_party/PHPExcel/Cell.php
>   on line 146

export krte waqt ye error aa rhi h

At the time of export this error is coming.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: check your php settings  and read other answers on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml , before you write new questions!

Comment: Checks if there are no two or more functions with the same name