# Destroying Data PHP - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, out-of-memory

I have an application PHP-MySQL, and for the visualisation of the data I used a library HighChart.
The problem is the HighChart do not give me always the best data for the same request.
I tried to display the list of one choice but it gived me an error this following:

```
 OutOfMemoryException in TurnoverQuery.php line 276:

    Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14460634 bytes)
```

I searched of course in Google, I found this solution:
[Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml)

And I changed the size of the memory: `ini_set` but in vein.

Can you give me please, is it a problem of size of memory or HighChart?

In the want to display a result of data

Comment: What's the best data?

Comment: Has nothing to do with HighCharts, as that's on the front-end. You are getting this error because your dataset (including any temporary variable storage) is too high. Without any code we have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: 128 megabytes is a lot of memory. Something in your php code is using all that memory, so php stops.  (It stops  because it's designed to run on busy shared web servers and it's generally a bad idea to use up all the physical memory on such machines).   It's hard to know *what* is using all the RAM in your php; you haven't told us how you feed data from MySQL to highcharts.

Comment: Perhaps you have some nested loops somewhere? Hard to say without seeing your code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Destroying Data PHP - MySQL and HighChart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559820/destroying-data-php-mysql-and-highchart)