# php - Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php

I'm creating a function that imports a csv file into a database. But an error has occurred, and i was wondering how to fix this.

> Error:
>   Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)

My function:

```
importFile("ingram", "ingram_fees.txt", "ingram_fees");

function importFile($company, $fileName, $tableName) {
    $filePath = "./ftp_imports/".$company."/".$fileName;
    $file = fopen($filePath, "r");
    $firstRowNames = fgetcsv($file);
    $columnNames = array();
    $rows = count($firstRowNames);
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $rows) {
        array_push($columnNames, toCamelCase($firstRowNames[$i]));
    }
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$tableName."'")) {
        if($result->num_rows !== 1) {
            $queryCreateTable = "CREAT TABLE $tableName (";
            $num = count($columnNames);
            $i = 0;
            while ($i < $num) {
                switch (gettype($columnNames[$i])) {
                    case 'string':
                        $queryCreateTable .= $columnNames[$i] . " VARCHAR(25)";
                        break;
                    case 'integer':
                        $queryCreateTable .= $columnNames[$i] . " DECIMAL(10,2)";
                        break;
                    case 'double':
                        $queryCreateTable .= $columnNames[$i] . " DECIMAL(10,2)";
                        break;
                    case 'NULL':
                        $queryCreateTable .= $columnNames[$i] . " VARCHAR(25)";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                if ($i !== ($num - 1)) {
                    $queryCreateTable .= ",";
                } else {
                    $queryCreateTable .= ");";
                }
            }
        }
    } else {//table already exists
        $queryDelAll = "TRUNCATE TABLE $tableName";
        $db->query($queryDelAll);

        $queryImport = <<<eof
            LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filePath'
            INTO TABLE $tableName
            FIELDS TERMINTED BY ','
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
            INGORE 1 LINES
            ($columnNames)
            eof;
            $db->query($queryImport);
        }
    }
```

and the function that gives the error because of its memory usage.

```
function toCamelCase($string, $capitalizeFirstCharacter = false) {
    $str = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $string)));
    if (!$capitalizeFirstCharacter) {
        $str[0] = strtolower($str[0]);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Because the `$columnNames` array is only 8 values long I don't know why the memory usage is that high.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks,
Per

Comment: Up the memory limit on your php installation, either via editing the `php.ini` file that's being used or by setting `ini_set("memory_limit", "...");` (example  `256M` for 256 Mb)

Comment: You need to update php ini memory_limit

Comment: `$i` is never incremented in your loop, and thus `$columnNames` is growing indefinitely.

Comment: @Blackhole whoops, that's an stupid mistake didn't saw that. Thanks for noticing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/561066/6521116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an infinite loop because you forgot to increment $i.

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < $rows) {
    array_push($columnNames, toCamelCase($firstRowNames[$i]));
}
```

better:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i < $rows) {
    array_push($columnNames, toCamelCase($firstRowNames[$i]));
    ++$i; 
}
```

Comment: stupid mistake. Thanks for help :)