# Fatal Error Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted on MySQL query on total amount in table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to get some data out of my database from a specific table which currently has 429,000 records.

I'm trying to total up the 'amount' column but running this query is giving me the error of:

**Fatal error**:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)

Here's my query

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT amount FROM salesOrderTransaction WHERE recordStatus=:recordStatus AND paymentStatus=:paymentStatus");
$stmt->bindValue(':recordStatus', '1', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':paymentStatus', 'Future', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$total = 0;

foreach ($results as $row) {
    $total = $total + $row['amount'];
}

$response['totalTransactionsOwed'] = $total;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18660082/6521116)

Comment: Why not use something like `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM ...` ?

Comment: Why have I been down voted?

Comment: I didn't downvote but this question suffers from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should have googled on "how to sum a column in MySQL" instead of doing something wrong and then asking about how to fix the consequences of the wrong approach.

Comment: Thanks for that, to be honest I didn't know the option of 'SUM' existed but a quick Google might have helped that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the value in just one row:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT sum(amount) as totalAmount FROM salesOrderTransaction WHERE recordStatus=:recordStatus AND paymentStatus=:paymentStatus");
```

Also check if you have index on recordStatus and paymentStatus

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the sum you need you can do:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT sum(amount) as sum FROM salesOrderTransaction WHERE recordStatus=:recordStatus AND paymentStatus=:paymentStatus");
$stmt->bindValue(':recordStatus', '1', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':paymentStatus', 'Future', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$response['totalTransactionsOwed'] = isset($row["sum"])?$row["sum"]:0;
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use *SUM* mysql function?

*select sum(amount) as amount from ...*

also you should read about **generators**, imho

Comment: Thanks Viktar, I'll have a look.