# Codeigniter 3.x gives me an error Fatal error of allowed memory of tried to allocate 65488 bytes

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to codiginter .When i load it gives memory error with following message  what should i do now

Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\system\database\DB_driver.php on line 1968

Comment: add the error text

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Add related code to question that led to the error. Controller, Model, anything custom written that is included within that request.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an infinite recursion scenario. Look:

- `Database_Model` and `Session_Model` extend Model.
- When you instance Database_Model, the constructor inherited from
  Model will instance two additional objects on the constructor,
  `$this->db` and `$this->session`.
- Those new objects also inherit from `Model`, so they will also instance
  their own `Database_Model` and `Session_Model`.
- And this goes on infinitely...

**Solution:**

- The correct way is to edit your `php.ini` file. Edit `memory_limit`
  to your desire value.

  As from your question, `128M` (which is the `default limit`) has been
  exceeded, so there is something seriously wrong with your code as it
  should not take that much.

  If you know why it takes that much and you want to allow it set
  `memory_limit` = `512M` or higher and you should be good.

  However try to avoid huge memory use, if the number of users are
  going to be more.
- Moreover, If you monitor your server, you will see that it is now
  probably using up most of the RAM and even swapping to disk.

  You should probably try to track down the exact bug in your code and
  fix it.

**Hope this is helpful**

Comment: No need to extend memory_limit, I think he have to check the queries which he is firing.

Comment: yep , he should check again his code , that's what i added now in my answer @kishor10d

Comment: how you come to know about his recursive scenario. He didn't provide anything as input.

Comment: this is what happens with most of PHP codiginter @kishor10d

Comment: check [Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml) @kishor10d