# Difficult with registering a document in arangodb-php

Tags: php, arangodb, arangodb-php

Has anyone also had this problem working with arangodb and php? If yes, could you help me understand what it would be. Thanks for listening!

> Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/clube/parceiros/vendor/triagens/arangodb/lib/triagens/ArangoDb/Document.php on line 333

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PHP code is trying to use more than 128 MB of memory in total. In PHP, a config option (`memory_limit`) controls the maximum amount of memory that each PHP process is allowed to use. It seems that your script hits that limit, so the PHP runtime aborts script execution.

To avoid this, you can either reconfigure the `memory_limit` value in your `php.ini` config file or adjust the PHP script so it uses less memory. It's hard to tell from here whether the latter is actually possible, because it mostly depends on what the script is actually doing, and this is neither explained nor shown in the question.