# Laravel Composer Loadclass Unknown

Tags: apache, laravel

I am having a problem. after I upload my laravel 5.4 on the live server, the server gives me an error in the error log

```
[03-Nov-2017 09:41:10] PHP Fatal error:  Couldn't execute method Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::composer\autoload\classloader::loadclass in Unknown on line 0
[03-Nov-2017 09:41:15] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /home/hosting_users/skymoontiger/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 41
```

What should I do?. thanks in advance...

Comment: The error say you don't have enough memory allowed for the script to run. It's an error well documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte) 
But first, I'll try to remove the /vendor directory + composer install && composer update.

Comment: Well, this server is not supporting composer. that is my problem too.

Comment: If you have a ssh access anyway, you can still install composer in your directory and call ./composer.phar install . If not, I found [this]( https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e) who could probably help you.

Comment: i had the same issue, and i have to incresase swap file or ram memory to fix this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml)