# Nu Soap response is empty for large data in PHP

Tags: php, response, nusoap

I used SOAP API to get files from Third party cloud endpoint.

**Technical Specification: **

```
PHP Version - 5.4.45
nusoap library - For Soap call.
```

About less than `3 MB` sized message can receive perfectly.We could not receive More than that size.

How can I get more sized data through the nusoap call in php?

Comment: What does happen when data is more than 3MB ? any error logs?

Comment: Thanks Thamarai,No error i could see. while i am printing the response nothing has been displayed.

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Is there any idea on this. Kindly help me. 

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe error logs created on your server check them. also, check your php memory_limit

Comment: I got below error 

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 27718127 bytes) in /data/apps/osc_cpq/lib/nusoap.php on line 876

Comment: Great you found the issue. Memory got exhausted increase the memory limit on `php.ini` will fix the issue

Comment: Duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/561066/2975952

Comment: Even i increased the memory_limit = 8192M, I couldn't get the result from nusoap response. :(

Comment: did you restart the server after modifying `php.ini`?

Comment: Yes I can see the modified value in phpinfo as well

Comment: Confirm with `phpinfo()` you increased the memory limit also check the error logs again.