# Sending a file via a form larger than 34 MB

Tags: php

There is a form that works and sends files, but when I try to send a file larger than 34 MB, an error is output

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate Y bytes)

Raising the memory_limit directive to 256 did not help!

The error refers to a string

```
$encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content))
```

which translates the file into code by type

```
OEJQUwABAAAAAAAAAAMAABdiAAAGKAAIAAMAAAAAAAFhWDhCSU0EBAAAAAABVxwBWgADGyVHHAFa
```

well, and accordingly in this form the file is larger than 128 MB. If someone knows how to convert the file differently, tell me please!

Comment: You can see the possible solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted (CodeIgniter + XML-RPC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml)