# PHP 7.1 Fatal error : Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, mysql, database

PHP version 7.1
I am trying to create a page where any user can upload an image, their name, comment, and their email. On the webpage, only the user name, comment and the image they uploaded will show up. I am not sure if this will help with anything but I am using Hostgator mysql database to store all the data. In previous questions (on this website - [PHP Warning mysqli_fetch_assoc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658238/php-warning-mysqli-fetch-assoc/59658568?noredirect=1#comment105477606_59658568)) I had errors regarding the fetch and get statements. However one of the solutions solved that issue but sadly now I get a warning saying:

**Fatal error:Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) in
gallery.php on line 45**

I have looked another post on this website regarding this same issue and I have been trying to follow the steps but was not successful. I would appreciate it if someone can guide me through this issue. Thanks in advance.

The codes it is referring to:

```
<div class="gallery-container">
<?php
include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

$sql = "SELECT imgFullNameGallery, titleGallery, descGallery FROM gallery ORDER BY orderGallery 
DESC;";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
echo "SQL statement failed!";
} else {

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $imgFullNameGallery, $titleGallery, $descGallery);


while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
echo '<a href="#">
<div style="background-image: url(img/gallery/'.$imgFullNameGallery.');"></div>
<h3>'.$titleGallery.'</h3>
<p>'.$descGallery.'</p>
</a>';
}
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try with this line `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M')` in your php.ini

Comment: With **tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes** that amount of 256M would not help, already 268435456 bytes exausted.

Comment: when I put in the code Julian Franco provided the error message went away but now nothing is showing up like no error message nor the actual web content. Thank you  though

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for php.ini. Inserting this line will cause PHP and/or Apache to fail to start.