# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 22133363 bytes)

Tags: php, laravel, apache2

I'm learning laravel and always ran the project in 127.0.0.1:8000 and everything was fine. I tried setting up the project for localhost apache2 and at first glance everything was fine, but when  next day i tried to open the project I got this error.

Where to look for the problem? And how to solve it?

Comment: Please refer this question on stack. [memory exhausted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml)

Comment: Your memory limit is set to 128M in PHP.  If you think you need more than that, you can raise it, but be careful you don't raise it too high. Otherwise, start with the route that you were trying to access, and check your controller and any middleware for places that you can reduce the memory footprint.