# Is there a Laravel-specific solution to increase this limit?

Tags: php, laravel

Error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36864 bytes) in /Users/username/Documents/username/laravel-api/vendor/fakerphp/faker/src/Faker/Provider/Base.php`

I don't want to increase this limit for the entire PHP but only for a specific project.

Comment: What caused this though?

Comment: I tried to seed 100000 items to the database using faker like the following:
`MyModel::factory(100000)->create();`
So obviously I exceeded the reserved limit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of 134217728 Bytes Exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted)

Comment: If this is for your seeder, then it is best to add the `ini_set` code on top of your `DatabaseSeeder` not in your `bootstrap/app.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put `ini_set('memory_limit', 'your value');` in the top of your `bootstrap/app.php` file. That way it's only for your Laravel project.

Comment: Before doing this though, you need to make sure that the issue is actually limit not sufficient. There are cases where limit issue is happening but only because of code gone wrong.