# I will increase the memory_limit, but in my file system there are so many php.ini files, so what should i do now?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12 bytes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666315/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-12-bytes)

I have so many php.ini file in my file system, so it is not possible for me to check which is important in that.

Comment: please add a comment to your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666315/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-12-bytes). Thanks!

Comment: Please use “please” and “because”.

Answer (score 2):

phpinfo() will show you an actual one