# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes)

Tags: php, memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-bytes)

Hi,

In my php page, I got the error as follows,

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes)
```

I tried to set memory limit using `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');`

But still I got the error.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It is impossible to solve this puzzle without actually seeing the actual code. Something in your page is eating up all that memory, until it finally hits the limit, then you get the error.

Comment: SO staff have to think of auto-close questions based on keywords. "allowed memory size" is one of such keywords

Comment: Post Code or try to remove all "loop-for-ever" code. That might help.

Comment: Try 'php_value memory_limit <your value>' in .htaccess. ini_set won't always work.

Answer (score 24):

128 megabytes *is* 134,217,728 bytes. You've used up that memory. You either need to set the limit *higher* (if you can; I don't know if PHP will allow that) or simply use less memory in your code.

Do you expect your page to be using a lot of memory? If so, maybe raising the limit (or setting it to -1, which is somewhat dangerous in terms of allowing unlimited memory use) is the right thing to do. If not, look through your code for places where you could be effectively leaking memory. You might want to try replacing sections of your page with "dummy" blocks, one at a time, until you find the offending section.

Comment: PHP usually spits out *exactly* where in code the allocation failed. The OP just didn't include that part in their code. Just pointing that out.

Comment: @Qix: If the OP has a leak though, the place where the allocation failed may be entirely unrelated to the leak location.

Comment: true, but it's a good place to start.