# php-excel-reader Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php

```
require_once 'Excel/reader.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

$data->read('Senator.xls');
```

I get the following error in my error.log

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)
```

The weird thing is, this works perfectly fine on my development instance. But not in production. What differences should I be looking for.

note: both envs have memory_limit=128M

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Comment: Read the legendary John Skeet's answer in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674197/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate?rq=1

Comment: Possible differences: different PHP modules installed using more memory, version of PHP, 32-bit or 64-bit PHP (average memory requirement is about 60% more on 64-bit that 32-bit)

Comment: I tried raising the limit, setting it to "-1". But still does not work. 
The file being read has only about 10 rows in it.

Answer (score 2):

Probably one server has a 64 bit processor. The GetInt4d bit shift doesn't work with 64 bit processors.

Use this hack to ensure correct result of the <<24 block on 32 and 64bit systems, just replace the code of the GetInt4d function with the following: Location : Excel/olereader.inc line no-27 ,function GetInt4d()

`$_or_24 = ord($data[$pos+3]);`

`if ($_or_24>=128) $_ord_24 = -abs((256-$_or_24) << 24); else $_ord_24 = ($_or_24&127) << 24;`

`return ord($data[$pos]) | (ord($data[$pos+1]) << 8) | (ord($data[$pos+2]) << 16) | $_ord_24;`

Comment: This cured the memory issue for me but the file still wouldn't fully import

Comment: This fixed the issue 

Answer (score 0):

Depends on witch line it's giving the error: mine is

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in [] on line 1688
```

it is the function

```
addcell($row, $col, $string, $info=null) {
```

in particular the foreach loop. As i understood it's info about color cell offset or something similar so i commented the loop and now it is using much less memory.

If you don't need the execution of such code you can comment it and try.