# Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted when reading large excel files

Tags: php, excel

I am getting below error while reading large .xls file say 29MB (3 sheets, 28000 rows/sheet) using **[Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/)**.

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in...**

I changed memory_limit in php.ini to 128M, and also tried change it run time as ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); for unlimited but error not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you could do '-1'.

You could try :

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
```

Comment: '-1' works great for my other small amount of file size. I also tried other options to change memory limit with 32M, 64M, 128M, 256M and 512M but issue not solved.

Answer (score 0):

`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` overrides the default [PHP memory limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

AND/OR

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', INCREASE TIME);
```

Comment: yes, I know ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');  overrides the default PHP memory limit, but the problem is still I'm getting fatal error for memory limit.

Comment: please check it in your php.ini file how much you have given it?

Comment: in php.ini I have set 256M

Comment: have you tried with ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); ? If yes,then probably the (while,for,...) loop is running infinitely OR debug with memory_get_usage function

Comment: `$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n"; // retunrs 5820096

$data->read("[my-filepath]"); // Fatal error occurs here

echo memory_get_usage() . "\n";`

This how my code looks and debug results commented there.

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081058/php-excel-reader-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted

Answer (score 0):

Probably one server has a 64 bit processor. The GetInt4d bit shift doesn't work with 64 bit processors.

Use this hack to ensure correct result of the <<24 block on 32 and 64bit systems, just replace the code of the GetInt4d function with the following:
Location : Excel/olereader.inc line no-27 ,function  GetInt4d()

`$_or_24 = ord($data[$pos+3]);`

`if ($_or_24>=128)
$_ord_24 = -abs((256-$_or_24) << 24);
else
$_ord_24 = ($_or_24&127) << 24;`

`return ord($data[$pos]) | (ord($data[$pos+1]) << 8) | (ord($data[$pos+2]) << 16) | $_ord_24;`