# How to use XMLReader to parse multiple, identically named attributes of XML element/sub-element

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

I'm using XMLReader and PHP to process a moderately-sized XML file (6mb) and basically break up the attribute data and insert it into my own database.  Problem is, each element has a variable number of subelements with identically named attributes.

Here's an example (this is open data about the government courtesy of govtrack.us):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<people>
    <person id='400001' lastname='Abercrombie' firstname='Neil' birthday='1938-06-26' gender='M' pvsid='26827' osid='N00007665' bioguideid='A000014' metavidid='Neil_Abercrombie' youtubeid='hawaiirep1' name='Rep. Neil Abercrombie [D, HI-1]' title='Rep.' state='HI' district='1' >
        <role type='rep' startdate='1985-01-03' enddate='1986-10-18' party='Democrat' state='HI' district='1' />
        <role type='rep' startdate='1991-01-03' enddate='1992-10-09' party='Democrat' state='HI' district='1' />
        <role type='rep' startdate='1993-01-05' enddate='1994-12-01' party='Democrat' state='HI' district='1' />
        <role type='rep' startdate='1995-01-04' enddate='1996-10-04' party='Democrat' state='HI' district='1' />
        <role type='rep' startdate='1997-01-07' enddate='1998-12-19' party='Democrat' state='HI' district='1' />
        <role type='rep' startdate='1999-01-06' enddate='2000-12-15' party='Democrat' state='HI' district='1' />
        <role type='rep' startdate='2001-01-03' enddate='2002-11-22' party='Democrat' state='HI' district='1' />
        <role type='rep' startdate='2003-01-07' enddate='2004-12-09' party='Democrat' state='HI' district='1' url='http://www.house.gov/abercrombie' />
        <role type='rep' startdate='2005-01-04' enddate='2006-12-08' party='Democrat' state='HI' district='1' url='http://www.house.gov/abercrombie' />
        <role type='rep' startdate='2007-01-04' enddate='2009-01-03' party='Democrat' state='HI' district='1' url='http://www.house.gov/abercrombie' />
        <role type='rep' startdate='2009-01-06' enddate='2010-03-01' party='Democrat' state='HI' district='1' url='http://www.house.gov/abercrombie' />
</person>
```

I don't need any fancy logic to be performed on the attributes.  At the beginning of my script, I check to see if I've already processed this particular record (based on the 'id' attribute), and then I grab pretty much every attribute and parse it into my db.  But there are two problems:

1) When I use this:

```
$p->getAttribute('id')
```

to get the 'id', it gives it to me twice, separate by as many line breaks as there are subelements in the element (I think the comment on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.getattribute.php) speaks to that, but I'm not sure what to do about it).

2) How do I access the attributes of each subelement sequentially?  This:

```
$p->getAttribute('startdate')
```

gives me every 'startdate' value separated by multiple line breaks.  I just need to grab the id of the element and then cycle through each of the 'role' subelements.

Any ideas?

For edification, here's the super-simple controller I have so far:

```
$f = base_url().'data/people.xml';
$p = new XMLReader;
$p->open($f);
while($p->read())
{
    if($this->_notImported('govtrack',$p->getAttribute('id')))
    {
            // here I just grab the attributes, put them into arrays to insert, like so:
            $insert = array('indiv_name' => $full_name,
                                    'indiv_first' => ($p->getAttribute(‘firstname’)),
                                    'indiv_last' => ($p->getAttribute(‘lastname’)),
                                    'indiv_middle' => ($p->getAttribute(‘middlename’)),
                                    'indiv_other' => ($p->getAttribute(‘namemod’)),
                                    'indiv_full_name' => $full_name,
                                    'indiv_title' => ($p->getAttribute(‘title’)),
                                    'indiv_dob' => ($p->getAttribute(‘birthday’)),
                                    'indiv_gender' => ($p->getAttribute(‘gender’)),
                                    'indiv_religion' => ($p->getAttribute(‘religion’)),
                                    'indiv_url' => ($url)
                                    );
```

For the element, this is not as difficult, but I don't know how to cycle through each of the 'role' subelements and grab the attributes separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are not checking for the appropriate *nodeType*, which is in fact related to the comment you linked: it matches both for the opening tag (ELEMENT) and the closing tag (END_ELEMENT).

Your second issue is also related to the missing *nodeType* check. After you fix that, you just have to check for the node's *name* to find out if it's a `<role>` or `<person>`.

Since I'm assuming you're also reading a large XML file, you probably want to know when you're passing to the next person tag... (via the END_ELEMENT *nodeType*) See my example below:

```
while($p->read()) {
    // check for nodeType here (opening tag only)
    if ($p->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        if ($p->name == 'person') {
            if ($this->_notImported('govtrack',$p->getAttribute('id'))) {
                // $insert['indiv_*'] stuff here
            } else {
                $insert = null; // skip record because it's already imported
            }
        } else if ($p->name == 'role') {
            // role stuff here
            $startdate = $p->getAttribute('startdate');
        }

    // check for closing </person> tag here
    } else if ($p->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $p->name == 'person') {
        if (isset($insert)) {
            // db insert here
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, your quotes `‘` must be replaced with proper quotes `'` if you want this to work.

Comment: Fantastic!!  I'm still having some trouble with the memory allocation, but this works a lot better and I think I'm on track to get it working.  (And I'm not sure what happened to my quotes; they're correct in my actual code, just not on SO).