# Running out of memory, but allowed is so much higher

Tags: php

Getting the following error, which I understand and have seen before. But one thing seems weird, it is trying to allocate an amount which is lower the the allowed memory size. Doesn't this seem weird?

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7680 bytes) in XXX on line 93
```

Could this be some kind of misconfiguration with memory management, I am using a cloud server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Comment: If you have a budget of $10 and you've spent $9 and you try to buy something for $2 you've gone over your allowable limit...

Comment: Please use the search (or google) before asking new questions - many have already been asked and answered. (Normally I wouldn't cite google but ... if you [google](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Allowed+memory+size+of+33554432+bytes+exhausted&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) your error, there's literally *pages* of results)

Comment: Wow, didn't understand how it worked - honest answer. No reason to be mean.

Comment: And actually it's not a duplicate of that bug as the one linked asks about how to increase it - not how memory allocation worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number "tried to allocate 7680 bytes" does not mean the total amount of memory the script allocates, but the last portion on which it exceeded the limit.

So let's say your script already allocated 33550000 b, tries to allocate another 7680 b. The total exceeds the memory limit and that's why the error appears.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give me a helpful answer and allowing me the better understand it rather then flame me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the memory limit is set smaller than what you're thinking it is set to?

You can use this to display the current limit

```
echo ini_get('memory_limit');
```

or increase it inline with

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
```

Of course you can see the entire php enviornment with

```
echo phpinfo();
```