# Allowed memory size in a Dedicated

Tags: wordpress, memory

l have a dedicated server with 24 GB RAM.
l have a news portal based on wordpress scrtipt and when l try to add SEO SearchTerms Tagging 2 plugin and activate it wp admin area giwing this error.
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 11508934 bytes) in /home/username/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 251
I tried everything, I made 1024 M in php.ini added define(’WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ’1024M’); in wp-config.php but non of them worked.
I need help if possible... thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Although it would make sense to figure out WHAT exactly is causing the memory error. In any case I had a similar problem and this fixed it for me.