# Php Myadmin upload large file error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262145 bytes)
```

I try to Import a csv file 199MB into mysql database.

```
upload_max_filesize = 300M
post_max_size = 300M
memory_limit = 32M
```

It's keep pop the error, what should I change in php.ini

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Comment: PHP's internal file upload handling is terminally stupid. memory_limit must be at LEAST as large as the upload_max/post_max.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: "Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted" and "memory_limit = 32M" -- 32MB == 32*1024*1024 == 33554432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`33554432 bytes` is exactly 32M.

Try to boost up your memory_limit alot.

Comment: Don't make it more than your ram. Put 1024M instead.

Answer (score 0):

You shoul try to increase the memory limit. In PHP > 5.2.1 the default value is 128M.

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit
;memory_limit = 32M
memory_limit = 128M
```

Comment: how much should i set

Comment: It depends on how much memory your server has. If you want only upload this file, you can increase the memory in 200M or 300M and after you finished your upload, you can set the memory in 128M.

Comment: You must restart your apache server.