# memory_limit on beanstalk ec2 instance

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, memory-limit

I am processing an image on my ec2 instance and I'm getting a memory limit error

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 36000 bytes)
```

I debugged on my localhost and found out that it works when I bump the memory limit from 128MB to 1024MB. (I am processing images from 8MB to 16MB).

My questions is if I have an amazon ec2 instance of **m1.small** (http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/#instance-details).

Can I safely set the php memory_limit to 1024MB?

Comment: what happend when you tried ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Comment: @Glavić not exactly a duplicate, questions are totally different