# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in joomla 3

Tags: memory, joomla

Getting following error at joomla admin, when click on Global Configuration option:

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/arena/public_html/libraries/phputf8/utils/unicode.php on line 49
,
i am using joomla 3.0.1

Comment: Two things....why aren't you using Joomla 3.3.1 which is the latest of the 3.x series? and have you done any research for this problem you're having?

Comment: actually my client has provided installed joomla and told to work on the same version ,is this version prob?if yes then i will ask my client to use latest version , i have google this prob , and its showing memory limit  prob ,and found result on this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte,but its not working on my server

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can solve this problem. By adding the init_set('memory_limit', $amount_of_memory) in your index.php file, by setting the memory_limit Apache variable at the .htaccess level using the php_value, or by modifying the global/local php.ini. We have discussed all the options here http://www.itoctopus.com/allowed-memory-size-of-x-bytes-exhausted-error-on-joomla . If none works, then most likely this is a hosting issue, and you should take it with your host.