# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes)

Tags: php

i have a problem with PHP i just want try to call method

i got error :

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 1 bytes) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\aa-acc\include\Produk_Method.php on line 13

and i have tried this answer :
[Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

and i still get this error:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1881931776) (tried to allocate
>   65488 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\aa-acc\include\Produk_Method.php on
>   line 13

this is my code:

on Produk.php

```
<?php

if(!defined('access_include')){
    define('access_include', '..');
}
include( access_include . '/include/start_up.incl.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
    $HeadTag->keyword = $Variable->WEBNAME . ', ' . $Variable->WEBNAME2;
    $HeadTag->description = $Variable->DESCRIPTION;
    echo $HeadTag->head_admin('Produk', 'produk');
?>

</head>
<body>

$ProdukMethod->GetProdukGroup('1');

$ProdukMethod->GetProdukCategory('1');

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Class Start_up

```
if(!defined('access_include')){
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
<?php
    include(access_include . '/include/class_variable.php');
    $Variable = new variable();

    include( access_include . '/include/head_metadata.incl.php');
    $HeadTag = new head_tag($Variable);

    include(access_include . '/include/Produk_Method.php');
    $ProdukMethod = new ProdukMethod();
?>
```

Class Variable

```
<?php
if(!defined('access_include')){
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}

class variable{
    public $WEBHOST = 'http://localhost:8080/aa-acc/';
    public $WEBNAME = 'aa-acc';
    public $WEBNAME2 = 'Anugrah Abadi Accessories';
    public $DESCRIPTION = 'Description';

}
?>
```

Class ProdukMethod

```
<?php
if(!defined('access_include')){
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
include(access_include . '/include/DataAccess.incl.php');
class ProdukMethod extends DataAccess{
    public function __construct(){

    }  
    public function GetProdukCategory($catname = ''){
        echo $this->GetProdukCategory($catname); //Error at this line
    }
    public function GetProdukGroup($groupname = ''){
        echo $this->GetProdukCategory($groupname);
    }
}

?>
```

Produk DataAccess

```
<?php
if(!defined('access_include')){
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}

class koneksi{
    private $HOSTNAME = 'localhost';
    private $USER = 'root';
    private $PASSWORD = '';
    private $DATABASE = 'aa-acc';

    protected function koneksi_sql(){
    $Condb = @new MySQLi($this->HOSTNAME, $this->USER, $this->PASSWORD, $this->DATABASE);
        $Condb->connect_errno and die ('Connect Failed : '.$Condb->connect_error);
        return $Condb;
    }
}

class DataAccess extends koneksi{
    private $ConDb;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->ConDb = $this->koneksi_sql();
    }

    protected function GetProdukCategory($catname){

    }
    protected function GetProdukGroup($groupname){

    }
}
?>
```

Can Someone help me??
thank you

Comment: Stop recursing `public function GetProdukCategory($catname = ''){
        echo $this->GetProdukCategory($catname); //Error at this line
    }`.... all you do is call this same method over and over again until it blows the stack

Comment: Perhaps your `echo $this->GetProdukCategory($catname);` should be `echo parent::GetProdukCategory($catname);`

Comment: woww this work, thank you.. maybe you can type it as answer.. i want to click checklist at answer

Answer (score 4):

Your `GetProdukCategory` method calls itself, resulting in a never-ending recursion. After a while PHP runs out of memory trying to allocate the stack for each entry into the function, and you get the error above. Fix the code in `GetProdukCategory` to do what you want it to do (probably not what it does at the moment).