# OutOfMemoryException symfony 3

Tags: symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

I am running Symfony3 with Doctrine and Sonata Admin. I don't think I need to get into details about the project. The problem is that while I am **editing** one of my big entities I get an:

> HTTP ERROR 500

When I cut down some properties of the Entity, I get an:

> OutOfMemoryException in FileProfilerStorage.php line 158:
>   Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 5371354 bytes)

**Tried:**
1. [Out of memory error in symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229637/out-of-memory-error-in-symfony)  *failed*
2. Changing php.ini memory_limit from 128M to 4048M (Step by step, I know it is too much), *everything failed*
3. `php -d memory_limit=1024M app/console cache:clear --env=prod`, various values, *failed*
4. also `php bin/console cache:clear` *failed*

Then, what's next?

Comment: When you changed `memory_limit` to `4048M` what error message it threw? I guess you changed it for PHP CLI or you haven't restarted your web server.

Comment: I didn't got any errors.. I haven't restarted the web server, but even now that I did, nothing changed. And I am definitely editing the correct php.ini.. @Martin

Comment: So when you didn't get any errors the problem is solved, right :)?

Comment: Oh, you meant that errors. I though you were talking about errors in the console. Anyway, I still got the same errors when trying to edit a Entity from localhost:8000/admin

Comment: My point is that if you think you changed the limit to 4GB and the error is still `Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes` then you didn't change the limit.

Comment: I didn't verified the memory with phpinfo() yesterday. But I did it today and it is changed to 4048M. Also today I don't have the same problem.. I didn't even turned off my laptop.. I guess that bug is hiding somewhere.