# Error in Symfony 3

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony3.x

I am trying to edit a record which have to choices and have to select value there.

```
$formMapper->add('addedBy', EntityType::class, [
             'class' => 'AppBundle:User', 'choice_label' => function ($user) {
                 return $user->getFullName();
             },
         ])

         ->add('medicalProvider', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'AppBundle:MedicalProvider', 'choice_label' => function ($medicalProvider) {
                 return $medicalProvider->getName();
             }, 
        ])
```

In Review section i have two entities form which i have to take values User and MedicalProvider , but when i load that things in choice_label, I am getting error like this.

:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 21348352 bytes) in :  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\OutOfMemoryException: Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 21348352 bytes) in D:\software\xampp\htdocs\meopin_2\trunk\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\FileProfilerStorage.php:158
Stack trace:

## 0 {main}

Next LogicException: Request stack is empty in D:\software\xampp\htdocs\meopin_2\trunk\var\cache\dev\classes.php:4690
Stack trace:

## 0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->terminateWithException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\OutOfMemoryException))

## 1 D:\software\xampp\htdocs\meopin_2\trunk\var\cache\dev\classes.php(3323): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\OutOfMemoryException))

## 2 D:\software\xampp\htdocs\meopin_2\trunk\var\cache\dev\classes.php(3366): Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\OutOfMemoryException), Array)

## 3 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler:: in classes.php.

Anyone can you please help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Out of memory error in symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229637/out-of-memory-error-in-symfony)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by extending memory limit.

But page tooks lot time to load anybody have any idea to minimize page loading time?

Comment: Try to search. There are many questions about performance and Symfony.