# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php

Tags: php, linux, laravel-4, amazon-ec2, out-of-memory

Laravel 4.2, Amazon ec2 Linux

PHP Fatal error:

```
Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3072 bytes) in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 78
```

Comment: Change your `memory_limit` setting in php.ini. You're barely letting your scripts use any memory at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Comment: @EdCottrell change into?

Comment: @MarlonBuendia just about anything higher than 256k (your current setting). For most useful applications, you need at least a few MB. I would start with `8MB` and see how it goes.

Comment: @EdCottrell I have `
ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');` in my php, will it work?

Comment: @MarlonBuendia No. The shorthand only works in php.ini, not in `ini_set`. [See the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes). Also, 1G is a bit excessive for most purposes.

Comment: @EdCottrell So what shall  I do change the memory_limit to 8MB etc/php.ini?

Comment: @MarlonBuendia Yes, change it in your php.ini file, but make sure you found the right file. I have posted an answer that will help you do that. Please remember to accept it if you found this helpful!

Comment: This is something you could have easily used a search engine to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** You need to increase your `memory_limit` setting in php.ini. You're barely letting your scripts use any memory at all.

## The Problem

The error message `Allowed memory size of 262144...` means you have a `memory_limit` setting of 256 kb. That is far too low. For most useful applications, you need at least a few MB. I would start with 8MB and see how it goes.

## The Solution

Change the `memory_limit` setting. In theory, you can do this two ways: (1) edit php.ini or (2) use `ini_set()`.

In practice, you cannot always use `ini_set('memory_limit', value);`. For one thing, some extensions, like suhosin, prevent scripts from setting the `memory_limit` in this way. For another, you have to be careful how you do it. For example, you proposed using `ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');`. But [the shorthand (`K`, `M`, `G`) only works in php.ini, not in `ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes). You would have to enter an actual number of bytes (e.g., `1073741824`). Also, `1G` is pretty excessive for most purposes; very, very few non-malicious PHP scripts need anything like that. Even pretty heavy frameworks like WordPress typically run well within 64 MB or so, even with lots of plugins loaded up.

## How to change the setting in php.ini

Figure out which php.ini file you are using (it's not uncommon to have several floating around, depending on how you installed things). You can do this in two ways:

1. Put this in a .php file and run it: `<?php phpinfo();`
2. On a command line, type `php -i | grep php.ini`. You should see a line that says something like `Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini` (the output may vary by system, of course).

Edit the file you just found by changing the line that starts with `memory_limit =` to something more appropriate, like

```
memory_limit = 8M
```

Feel free to bump that number up as needed, but I would recommend starting small (not `1G`) to prevent bringing your server to its knees accidentally.

One caveat: if this is a testing/development machine and you are running a debugger or profiler like xdebug, you may want to start much higher, and `1G` is not insane. But don't start with such a high number on a production machine; work your way up to it.