# php memory exhausted clean LEMP stack

Tags: php, nginx

I just installed a clean LEMP stack on a droplet on digital ocean. Everything seems te be working fine. It I notice that if I do something on the command line with php. I will get a php fatal error about memory exhausted:

`PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in Unknown on line 0`

I tried rebooting the system and run the commands immediately. Still the same problem. I also changed the memory limit from the default 128M to 265M. which is also reflected by `phpinfo()`.

Finally, the free command shows that there is memory left, and also swap is enabled:

`total used free shared buffers cached
Mem: 501792 468888 32904 5412 68584 253116
-/+ buffers/cache: 147188 354604
Swap: 1048572 4396`

Did I do something wrong with the php5-fpm configuration? I usually work with a LAMP stack ... so I don't know if this is nginx  php5-fpm specific.

Comment: 262144 thats not a lot of memory you have allocated

Comment: That was my first thought too. That is roughly 26kb of memory that is set as the limit. Are you sure you set the allowed memory size right?

Comment: i think `echo 'fish';` takes up more memory than that. so clearly the settings for the limits are wrong, somewhere - whats in php.ini? can you post the actual phpinfo results for memory allocation?

Comment: maybe this answer could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte

Comment: .. command line memory allocation may not be the same as the allocation 'via web server' they often use separate php.ini files, on the command line run `php -i`

Comment: I found the problem. It has been mentioned in other threads too. The php.ini in cli folder was not set correctly: 128MB instead of 128M.

Everything was working because the fpm was set correctly.