# I have createed a cron file which is call recursively it gives memory allocation

Tags: php, memory-management

I am using this in cron File so that it will slow my system `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`. Again and again 
I have created a `cron` PHP script which is called recursively. It is giving me this error:

> Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes)

I have seen some solutions like increasing the size of memory allocation limit in `php.ini`. But this is not a permanent solution, and I want permanent solution for this. How can I delete the address of previous stack memory?

Comment: Can you show your code and your cronjob? There's not enough info here to solve it. Now, you CAN set the memory limit from inside the script: `ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');`, and I will note that your default of 32M is a bit small.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Comment: I have already said ini_set is not permanent solution already tried this. so please any thing else

Comment: @GhanshyamKumar you should've checked other answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/5254547/2044039 . editing php.ini is a permanent solution whilst setting options with ini_set isn't.

Comment: @AlexanderM. yes i have seen this problem on many other questions but i have using thing in cron file. its not gives me appropriate solution.Beacause I have already used this at `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` it will slow the system because of memory....

Comment: We can't give you an appropriate solution without knowing what is causing the problem. Is it badly written code? What is using large amounts of memory? Are you building large arrays in memory? How can we tell when we can't see what your code is doing or how it works? You want a solution, you have to provide us with sufficient information to identify the problem.

Comment: And why are you running a cron script recursively?

Comment: @MarkBaker I did'nt use any array, I am using only variables with recursive, recursice function for synchronize the database of local server to main server

Answer (score 0):

Editing php.ini is a permanent solution whilst setting options with ini_set isn't.

For cronjobs executed you specify in `crontab`, in order to configure php options for cli, you should edit the proper ini file.

> If php-SAPI.ini exists (where SAPI is the SAPI in use, so, for
>   example, php-cli.ini or php-apache.ini), it is used instead of
>   php.ini. The SAPI name can be determined with php_sapi_name().

([Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php))

To get the loaded ini file location, execute:

```
$ php -i | grep ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini
```

So, in my case, to set memory limit for cron, I would edit `/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini`.