# Yii2 : Memory Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, yii2-advanced-app

My project is running fine on localhost. But if I uploaded it to my domain, it shows an error while opening a form (which contains a wbraganca dynamic form in it). The error is as follows -

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 81 bytes)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Comment: but I don't know where to insert `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` because the form is working on localhost.

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thanks.

Comment: It's too late now, but thanks, it worked for me.