# W3Total Cache Memory Error

Tags: wordpress, caching

I am Getting Error On WordPress When I Activate w3 Total Cache

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 196608 bytes) in /home/vika8467/public_html/blog/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/lib/W3/ConfigKeys.php on line 1329

How do I fix this?

Comment: Increase memory limit above 32MB, find out what's using a lot of memory and optimize it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Comment: **Thanks** mate <3