# Why I get Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted error

Tags: php, arrays

I just can not find any error at my code. the problem coming with the `array_push` method (Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted).

Code:

```
<?php
    require "dbConnect.php";
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    if ($username != '') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $data = array();

        if (isset($check)) {
            echo "4";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "2";
                array_push ($data, array('name'=>$row[1], 'username'=>$row[2], 'password'=>$row[3], 'email'=>$row[4]));
            }

            echo json_encode(array("response"=>$data));
            mysqli_close($con);

        } else {
            echo "0";
        }
    } else {
        echo "3";
    }
?>
```

Error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in <b>/home/u766232015/public_html/phpScripts/getUSerData.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
```

Answer (score 2):

That while() loop isn't going to ever stop looping, nothing is being changed inside it. You need to move the **mysqli_fetch_array** call to the loop condition, e.g.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem solved but now there is another one. I get back from the server an empty JSONObject ({"result":[]}). Maybe you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Your script is using too much memory. This can often happen in PHP if you have a loop that has run out of control and you are creating objects or adding to arrays on each pass of the loop.

See this post on SO :
[Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Check if your `while()` is not an infinite loop ;)

Comment: Thanks that was the issue

Comment: Answer to your question below : can you do a `print_r($data);` just before the `json_encode()` ?

Comment: Actually the program don't get into the loop

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);` => where is `$con` ?

Comment: There is no problem with $con because I know that the program can find the user name in my table (The program can get in the 'if( isset($check))'). The problem comes with the loop.

Comment: Can you update your code with the solution of @iainn ? Maybe try some `print_r($row);` and tell us what it returns

Comment: I updated the post, so now I can explain it better. It print 4 but not print 2 so you can understand that the condition: '$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)' is true from the start even when I have rows at my table (users)...

Comment: How about when you comment the `$check` var and the `if(isset($check){ ... }` condition ?

Comment: Check the code, I already did it. That is work and return me 4 (that situation)

Comment: No, I was meaning **remove** theses lines just to see

Comment: I did not understand what you meant