# Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php

I am getting this problem while deleting multiple items from my database. Any suggestions on fixing this problem.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 43148176 bytes) in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte)

Comment: This could be caused by a billion different things. Definite a duplicate of above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `php.ini` and edit the `memory_limit` line like below:

```
memory_limit = 512M
```

Probably it'll fix it but it may not. If you can not solve it, please be more spesific, add more information.