# ajax 500 internal server error but works some times

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am stuck on a peculiar problem. My ajax (jquery COMET) not working in production server. It had workable. **After 2/3 month** my ajax showing 500 internal server error.

I have updated my CodeIgniter to 3.1.3 still nothing happened. But strange is sometime the ajax is works fine (probably after refresh) and most of the time it showing 500 internal error.

What I have tried so far

- `pconnect` set to `TRUE` in `config.php` (not worked)
- `dbriver` changed both in `mysqli` and `pdo` nothing helped
- `.htaccess` tried in many ways. My current one is

  ```
   RewriteEngine On

   #redirect http to https
   #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   #RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|static|assets|avatars|uploads|robots\.txt)
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx
  ```

Also tried this htaccess

https://gist.github.com/rejoan/38e59d34ba4f667b78c11b637c48c733

More info for helpers

> There is `https` in production server
>
> Locally no such problem like this
>
> when try `mysqli` sometime it become very slow so now using `pdo` as
>   dbdriver
>
> I have huge ajax request on this project because it is a chat system

[image: see console]

Comment: Have you checked the error logs for a more definitive description?

Comment: It has the answers you're looking for - time to dig in.

Comment: @JayBlanchard as far as i can see this error in error_log `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/webc..`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes checked all file full of this line `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/xxx/public_html/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_result.php on line 180` from 22-december to 10th january