# MPDF pdf is not opening in any browser, no error showing in Codeignitor

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

i've used mpdf for dynamic pdf generation, PDF is working fine but in online server when i'm trying to preview the pdf in browser or download it to my pc , it shows "Unable to Load Pdf".
I've also tried to check it into editor, i've not found any curropted error symbol.

```
Ob_clean(); // not working for me
```

here is my code:-

```
<?php         
        require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

        $mpdf->WriteHTML('

            <table style="text-align:center; background: '.$color1.'; color: '.$color2.'; width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 50%; font-size: 45px;">
                        HI,
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 100%;">
                        <table style="width: 80%; border: 4px solid #fff;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>I am</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-size: 32px;">'.$_POST['input1'].'</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 100%;">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-size: 20px;">'.$_POST['input2'].'</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>



        ');
        $file_name = "resume.pdf";

        $mpdf->Output($file_name, 'I');
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mpdf needs PHP 5.4+
Make sure that you provide the following required PHP modules:

- gd
- mbstring

If not for example in Linux we can install by using following two commands(change 7.0 to your server's PHP version)

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

**IMPORTANT** : Also check the group where resume.pdf saving is www-data and it has write permission there recursively.
We can add it by following commands

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data folderpathhere/
sudo chmod -R g+w folderpathhere/
```

Comment: both mbstring & gd extensions are enabled and my php version is also 7.1. i'm trying to fix this for 3 days , no errors is showing. I've also checked it in editor.

Comment: What about file permissions?

Comment: Open Apache error log..and check latest errors..it will mostly inside /var/log/apache2/ folder

Comment: here is the error in error log-  PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 400556032 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Check error time too...if it's because pdf solve by following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte/415818

Comment: Will `sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd` work on Fedora or Windows?

Comment: i've updated the memory size to unlimited. but not working at all

Comment: [Wed Oct 02 03:10:02.427634 2019] [core:crit] [pid 16822] (13)Permission denied: [client 03.174.05.106:48928] AH00529: /home/user/public_html/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/user/public_html/' is executable

Comment: sudo chmod 644 /home/user/public_html/.htaccess
sudo chmod 755 /home/user/public_html/

Comment: Did u give write permission where resume.pdf is generating?