# Laravel with AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel

In one line:- Want to send post data to controller using ajax.

**This question is asked many times before.**

**But i couldn't see the solution to my problem.**

My problem is:- **"message": "Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262148096 bytes)"** in the preview tab of network in DEV TOOLS CHROME.
I saw this link [Allowed Memory size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415801/allowed-memory-size-of-33554432-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-43148176-byte) too but no benefit.
When only three variables are posted, Why is this problem coming?

My controller code

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($request);
    echo "</pre>";

}
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$('body').on('click', '.submit_followers', function() {
    $('#pactId').val($(this).attr('data-pact'));
    $('#userId').val($(this).attr('data-user'));
    $('#followersForm').trigger('submit');
});
$(document).ready( function () {
   $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
  });
});
$('body').on('submit', '#followersForm', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{route('pacts.addFollowers')}}",
            data: {
                '_token':$('input[name="_token"]').val(),
                'pactId': $('#pactId').val(),
                'userId': $('#userId').val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    });
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="col-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-violet btn-side-rounded submit_followers" data-user="{{Auth::id()}}" data-pact="{{$pact->id}}" type="button"><i class="fa fa-hand-spock-o"></i> Follow</button>
        </div>
{!! Form::open( [ 'method'=>'Post','id'=>'followersForm' ] ) !!}
@csrf
{!!Form::hidden( 'pactId',"",['id'=>'pactId'] )!!}
{!!Form::hidden( 'userId',"",['id'=>'userId'] )!!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Routes one is resource and another is post**

```
Route::resource("/pactsFollowers","pactsFollowersController");
Route::post('pactsFollowersController/store', 'pactsFollowersController@store')->name('pacts.addFollowers');
```

Comment: Use `dd($request)` `print_r` will trip up with cyclical references which request has

Comment: Thanks. It worked.
Ok can you please explain a little more? Because i couldn't understand cyclical references.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
      dd($request);
}
```

Comment: Please select this answer and give upvote this answer if it's help for you thank you...